# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log\left (\frac{n^2}{1+n^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to evaluate the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \left(\dfrac{n^2}{1+n^2}\right)$$
- In this case the terms are negative

- $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \log  \left(\dfrac{n^2}{1+n^2}\right)=\log 1=0$
- Now I'm not sure about the application of a test
  $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac {\log \left(\frac{n^2}{1+n^2}\right)}{\left(\frac {1}{2}\right)^n}=0$

being $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac {1}{2}\right)^n$ is a geometric series that converges.

Comment: Since $\log(1+x)\sim x$ as $x\to 0$ we have $\log(1 - \frac{1}{1+n^2}) \sim - \frac{1}{1+n^2}$. If you want to use the comparison test you should try to compare to the series $\sum \frac{1}{1+n^2}$ (or simply $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$).

Comment: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \log \left(\frac{n^2}{1+n^2}\right)=\log (\pi  \text{csch}(\pi ))$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Sure, but showing the OP how to derive or prove this is sort of the crux of the matter.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk You should make that an answer and show some detail, it would be interesting for those who don't know those things, yet.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes. Proving is hard.:P

Comment: Anne: to prove convergence, @Winther's approach is one of the simplest (I would actually recommend writing $-\log\frac{1+n^2}{n^2} = -\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \sim_{n\to\infty} -\frac{1}{n^2}$ to avoid pesky $+1$'s). Now, why did you decide to compare it to a geometric series -- what prompted you to do so? (it doesn't work, so understand why you chose to try that is crucial to helping you).

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk It can't be that hard: John Wallis did the analogous $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \log \left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)$ in 1655.

Comment: @Anne are you looking for the convergence or for the value?

Comment: For large $n$, the partial sum of the first $n$ terms is about $\frac1n -\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{4n^4}$ from the limit

Comment: The sum is equal to the following integral: $$\int_0^{2 \pi} dt \, \left (\frac1{1-e^{-t}} - \frac1{t} - \frac12 \right ) $$

Comment: @ProfessorVector The series you mention is much easier to compute, due to huge cancellations that do not occur in the series the OP is asking about.

Comment: @ClementC. I thought the geometric series because it converges. I'm finding the series quite difficult and thank you and Winther for your help!!!

Comment: @Did My bad, John Wallis managed the considerably more difficult $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \log \left(1-\frac1{(2n-1)^2}\right)$, where those cancellations don't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For comparison test with $-\frac{1}{n^2}$

$$\frac{\log \left(\dfrac{n^2}{1+n^2}\right)}{-\frac{1}{n^2}}=\log \left(\dfrac{1+n^2}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}=\log \left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\to1$$

Comment: But besides showing convergence, the OP's clearly stated goal is to *evaluate* the sum.

Comment: @ClementC. Anne has declared her doubt on the test, I've asked a clarification on the OP. Thanks!

Comment: @ClementC    $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  \frac{log(1+x)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  \frac{1}{1+x}=1$
and then $log (1+x) \sim x $ for  $x \rightarrow 0$
$log(\frac{n^2}{1+n^2})=log(\frac{1}{\frac{1+n^2}{n^2}})=-log (1+ \frac {1}{n^2}) \sim - \frac {1}{n^2}$ for  $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @ClementC.
Applying the asindotic comparison test:
$\frac{log(\frac{n^2}{1+n^2} )}{- \frac {1}{n^2}}=\frac{-log(\frac{n^2}{1+n^2} )}{- \frac {1}{n^2}}=\frac{log(\frac{n^2}{1+n^2} )}{\frac {1}{n^2}}\rightarrow 1$  for  $n \rightarrow \infty$.
Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty log(\frac{n^2}{1+n^2})$ converges, too.
is it correct?

Comment: @Anne Yes Anne it is correct! The comparison test is valid for series whiche terms are eventually positive or negative.

Comment: @Anne Could you please confirm that you are looking for convergence and not for the value? Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi forgive me if i didn't answer...for the convergence

Comment: @gimusi thanks for your help

Comment: @Anne You are welcome! All the mate here thought that you were asking for the value. Bye

Answer (score 14):

The given series is convergent by comparison with $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^2}$. An explicit evaluation can be performed along the following line:
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\log\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}=-\log\prod_{n\ge1}\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)=-\log\frac{\sinh\pi}\pi=\color{red}{\log\frac\pi{\sinh\pi}}$$
by invoking $\frac{\sin z}z=\prod_{n\ge1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$, i.e. the Weierstrass product for the sine function.

Comment: I want to learn more about these things, in a systematic manner. please tell me path. just out of high school. Thank for good answer

Comment: @KingTut: have a look at [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view), I wish you may learn some intersting tricks there.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks for the reference, I also will have a look to it!

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{equation}
\mbox{Note that}\quad\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\ln\pars{n^{2} \over 1 + n^{2}} =
\ln\pars{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{%
\lim_{N \to \infty}\prod_{n = 1}^{N}{n^{2} \over n^{2} + 1}}}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{align}
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{%
\lim_{N \to \infty}\prod_{n = 1}^{N}{n^{2} \over n^{2} + 1}}} & =
\lim_{N \to \infty}\verts{\prod_{n = 1}^{N}{n \over n - \ic}}^{2} =
\lim_{N \to \infty}\verts{N! \over \pars{1 - \ic}^{\large\overline{N}}}^{2}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{N \to \infty}\verts{N! \over
\Gamma\pars{1 - \ic + N}/\Gamma\pars{1 - \ic}}^{2} =
\verts{\Gamma\pars{1 - \ic}}^{2}
\lim_{N \to \infty}\verts{N! \over \pars{N - \ic}!}^{2}
\\[5mm] & =
\Gamma\pars{1 - \ic}\
\overbrace{\Gamma\pars{1 + \ic}}^{\ds{\ic\,\Gamma\pars{\ic}}}\
\lim_{N \to \infty}\verts{\root{2\pi}N^{N + 1/2}\expo{-N} \over
\root{2\pi}\pars{N - \ic}^{N - \ic + 1/2}\expo{-\pars{N - \ic}}}^{2}
\\[5mm] & =
\ic\ \overbrace{\quad\bracks{\Gamma\pars{1 - \ic}\Gamma\pars{\ic}}\quad}
^{\ds{{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi\ic}} = -\ic\,{\pi \over \sinh\pars{\pi}}}}\
\lim_{N \to \infty}\verts{1 \over
N^{-\ic}\pars{1 - \ic/N}^{N - \ic + 1/2}\expo{\ic}}^{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pi \over \sinh\pars{\pi}}
\lim_{N \to \infty}\verts{1 \over \expo{-\ic\ln\pars{N}}}^{2} =
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{{\pi \over \sinh\pars{\pi}}}}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} lead to

$$
\bbx{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\ln\pars{n^{2} \over 1 + n^{2}} =
\ln\pars{\pi \over \sinh\pars{\pi}}} \approx -1.3018 \\
$$